# How to get the output from console.timeEnd() in JS Console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I'd like to be able to get the string returned from `console.timeEnd('t')` in my Google Chrome Javascript Console.

In this example below, I'd like one variable which would contain `"t: 0.276ms"`

```
> console.time('t'); console.timeEnd('t');
  t: 0.276ms
< undefined
```

Is this something doable?

Comment: Before you need to put console.time('t');

Comment: no need label, default label is `default`

Answer (score 60, accepted):

In Google Chrome 23.0.1262.2 (Official Build 155904) dev, it looks like it's impossible. The only way I found to be able to calculate time with accuracy is to use `window.performance.webkitNow()`

Here's a simple example:

```
var start = window.performance.now();
...
var end = window.performance.now();
var time = end - start;
```

Read more at http://updates.html5rocks.com/2012/08/When-milliseconds-are-not-enough-performance-now

Comment: Would be nice if `console.timeEnd()` just returned the elapsed time

Comment: I slapped this util class together based on performance.now() as it's widely accepted

- https://caniuse.com/?search=performance.now
- https://stackblitz.com/edit/benchy?file=benchy.ts,index.ts

Answer (score 28):

simply you can use

```
var begin=Date.now();
something here ...;
var end= Date.now();

var timeSpent=(end-begin)/1000+"secs";
```

this is the simplest way and it will work on any browser not in only chrome

Comment: See this article for reasons why window.performance.now() may be a better option: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2012/08/When-milliseconds-are-not-enough-performance-now

The API is well supported now, too: https://caniuse.com/#search=performance.now

Answer (score 8):

Small helper to do some time measuring. `timerEnd` returns the time in ms, also the `timers` object contains information about how many times the timer with this name was used, the sum of all measured times and the average of the measurements. I find this quite useful, since the measured time for an operation depends on many factors, so it's best to measure it several times and look at the average.

```
var timers = {};
function timer(name) {
    timers[name + '_start'] = window.performance.now();
}

function timerEnd(name) {
    if (!timers[name + '_start']) return undefined;
    var time = window.performance.now() - timers[name + '_start'];
    var amount = timers[name + '_amount'] = timers[name + '_amount'] ? timers[name + '_amount'] + 1 : 1;
    var sum = timers[name + '_sum'] = timers[name + '_sum'] ? timers[name + '_sum'] + time : time;
    timers[name + '_avg'] = sum / amount;
    delete timers[name + '_start'];
    return time;
}
```

Answer (score -5):

console.timeEnd() function puts the time to console, and returns the value
so you can save it to variable

```
var c = console.timeEnd('a');
c/1000+'s';
```

or you can save this variable to window object for latest usage

```
window.c = console.timeEnd('b');
window.c
```

Comment: Actually, seems it is working in FireBug, but not Chrome Inspector.

Comment: As Console API is not an official standard, I guess this explains why they behave differently.