# Can we print/store the value of console.time() - console.timeEnd()?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I was wondering if we could get the value that a `console.time()` prints and store it in a variable or write to a log file or something. Basically, can we have the execution time for purposes other than printing on the console?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the output from console.timeEnd() in JS Console?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12492979/how-to-get-the-output-from-console-timeend-in-js-console)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For measuring execution times, there is the `performance` object. In its most simple use you would do [`start = performance.now()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/now).

But there are more features for measuring intervals, like [`performance.mark(name)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/mark) which creates a timestamp in the browser's performance entry buffer with the given name, and then [`measure(name, fromname, toname)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Performance/measure) which measures the delay between two marks and stores the result with a new name, ...etc.

In nodejs there is [`process.hrtime.bigint()`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_bigint), which returns a bigint representing nanoseconds. For older nodejs versions you can use [`process.hrtime([time])`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_process_hrtime_time) which returns two integers in an array: [seconds, nanoseconds].

The [`performance-now` npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/performance-now) is based on the latter and mimics the `performance.now()` behaviour.

Comment: I just used `performance.now()` and it works. How different is it from the `Date.now()` method mentioned by @Icehorn mentioned above?

Comment: It gives a different output (a floating point that represents the number of milliseconds with more precision, sometimes up to microsecond) and does not get influenced when someone changes the PC's clock.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Date.now()` in order to retrieve the current time.

```js
> Date.now()
>> 1552371509583
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now

Comment: what would be better among performance.now(), the 'performance-now' module or the Date.now() method?

Comment: `performance.now()` takes more time to execute and `Date.now()` gives me a rounded off value. [performance-now](https://www.npmjs.com/package/performance-now) seemed the most suitable for my use case. Guess I answered my own question then!

Comment: @RohitMishra, the performance-now module uses nodejs' `process.hrtime`. You'll want to use `process.hrtime.bigint()` when on nodejs 10.7 or higher.

Comment: yup! I tried that and it works fine. If I `require("performance-now");`, does it add an overhead in comparison to using `process.hrtime.bigint()` ? @trincot

Comment: @RohitMishra, it seems to be using `process.hrtime()`, not `process.hrtime.bigint()`, which means it merges the two values that are returned, dividing by 1000000, to get microseconds. That is what the tiny overhead is about. But now that `process.hrtime.bigint()` is available, I don't see much advantage in using the module.

Comment: got it. :) going ahead with `process.hrtime.bigint()`. thanks for the clarifications :)